# ZPL Code 128 doesn't match mPDF Code 128 output

Tags: mpdf, zpl, code128

I'm trying to print a Code 128 (Subset A?) barcode to a Zebra label printer.  It looks to be printing, and can be scanned by ZXing barcode scanner on my phone, but when using a barcode scanner, it won't read.

Generating the same barcode using MPDF (`type="C128A"`), generates a barcode with different bars that the barcode scanner we're using does read.

Here's my ZPL: [(ZPL Output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBzBR.png)

```
^XA

^BY4,2,164^FT70,330^BCN,,Y,N,Y,N
^FD>9171716171724161925^FS

^XZ
```

And the equivalent barcode tag used in mPDF: [(mPDF Output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5TVa.jpg)

```
<barcode code="110118039" type="C128A" size="1.5"/>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing differently between the two would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was scanner configuration at the user end.  Despite the differences in bars, both of the above are actually reading correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a few problems

1. You have a ">" in your ZPL within the FD field.
2. The data you have encoded is not the exact number you are trying to get a barcode for. I wonder how you got what you got, and how it's generating the desired number.
3. I see you are using the UCC Check Digit = Y parameter. Default is N. You probably don't need this parameter.

Proper ZPL:

```
^XA
^FO100,100^BY3
^BCN,100,Y,N,N
^FD110118039^FS
^XZ
```